# why are vectors not a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Given that S is a subspace {[ $x_1$ $x_1$ $x_1$ ] | $x_1$  is a real number}

$\vec u$ = [1 0 1] and  $\vec v$= [0 1 0] where u and v are vectors.

Why are $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ not a basis for S?

Comment: Basis vectors necessarily should belong to the space they span. Now think if $u$ and $v$ belong to $S$.

Comment: But since [1 0 1] and [0 1 0] do not meet the conditions of S they don't span S?

Comment: @RacketBeginner $S$ is a subset of the span of $\vec u$ and $\vec v$, so they do span it in that sense, but as others have pointed out, neither is a member of $S$.

Answer (score 2):

A basis $B$ of a vector space $V$ is a linearly independent **subset of $V$** that spans $V$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is the definition of a basis? There should be three distinct parts.

Comment: The vectors need to be linearly independent and the vectors must span S?

Comment: But since [1 0 1] and [0 1 0] do not meet the conditions of S they don't span S?

Comment: I see now that I didn't read your question carefully. Kasters comment above is correct.